# One word for "Ready to Test"

Tags: single-word-requests

We have a ticketing system for doing software development.

We would like to put tickets into a state where it is "Ready to Test".

But those words do not fit into the space allocated on the label.

What is one word that means the same thing?

Comment: You might get better/more answers in UX/UI SE as this is specialized language.  I'm partial to using verbs in buttons as they trigger actions.  "Ready to Test" is a status not an action.

Comment: It might help for context if you included the terms for the other states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most correct term would be testable; which would save you a few characters as well!

> test·a·ble
>   ˈtestəb(ə)l
>
> adjective;
>   able to be tested or tried.

source: http://www.dictionary.com/

Comment: Testable means able to be tested, not ready to test.  For example: String Theory is an untestable hypothesis, but Newton's 3rd Law of motion is a testable hypothesis, because there are tests able to be done to prove or disprove it.  With software, you can have code that is able to be tested, but not ready to be tested because it is being actively worked on.

Answer (score 0):

If you can program the button so it's greyed out before the ticket is ready to test, then *Test* would be enough. Otherwise *test-ready*, but that only saves one character.

Comment: Good thought, but is a state button so it will cycle through a few different states "unassigned", "done".

Answer (score 0):

### It depends a bit on what you mean by "Ready to Test"

Software development typically includes several rounds of different kinds of testing.  So, depending on what exactly you mean, it could be "Alpha", "Beta", Release Candidate often abbreviated "RC", or Bleeding Edge often abbreviated "BE".  RC and BE are synonymous.

A typical product lifecycle looks like this:

**Prealpha**: You are still too early in development to begin any formal testing

**Alpha:** Your software is ready enough to begin testing, but not yet containing all of the planned features.

**Beta:** Your software is considered feature complete, but needs further testing and is not fully stable, balanced, and optimized.

**(RC)Release Candidate** or **(BE)Bleeding Edge**: When you have done due diligence with internal testing and want to release it to a limited audience, to confirm that it is stable when actual users handle it outside of your controlled environment.

**Release** or **Stable**: This means you're confident that there are no more bugs, and that it is in a ready state for general use.  Any changes from here out are typically only security patches.

**Sunset:** This is a release version that is so old that you will no longer offer support or patches for it.

**(EoL) End of Life:** This means that the software is longer useable in normal environments and you have no intention of patching it to make it usable.

**There is also "open beta" which is not so well defined, but generally means software that is considered done enough to sell, but the developers still foresee major feature changes after releasing it.*

***These terms are specific to software design.  If you are an engineer, you would call "Ready to Test" the prototyping stage.  If you are a researcher, you may call it the experimental stage.  If you are a student, you may call it prepared.  So, knowing your context is pretty important to picking the right word here.*